# Android problem with 2 annotation type in MapBox

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-plugin

I try to use two types of annotation in my app Symbol and Fill,
after I declare SymbolManager as

```
  symbolManager = new SymbolManager(mMapView, mMapboxMap, style);
```

I want to declare FillManager as

```
fillManager= new FillManager(mMapView, mMapboxMap,style);
```

The problem is after and only when I declare the two types the listener addDragListener() stop working

I try to create a square with symbols on the edges and fill it with color
the symbol I can drag to change the shape of the square and the fill area I can drag from location to location

if I define SymbolManager after FillManager the addDragListener of SymbolManager worked.
But if  I define FillManager after SymbolManager the addDragListener of SymbolManager doesn't work

if I don't define SymbolManager but define the FillManager I don't see the fill annotation

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the case that the listeners for whichever manager is declared last take precedence, since `SymbolManager` and `FillManager` both inherit from `AnnotationManager`.

That being said, it sounds like you are trying to implement something similar to the functionality demonstrated in [this land select example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/satellite-land-select/) in the Mapbox Android documentation. If so, I would recommend following the logic outlined there rather than trying to use a `SymbolManager` and `FillManager` in conjunction.